# How to interpret query process GB in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, python-bigquery

I am using a free trial of Google bigquery. This is the query that I am using.

```
select * from `test`.events where subject_id = 124 and id = 256064 and time >= '2166-01-15T14:00:00' and time <='2166-01-15T14:15:00' and id_1 in (3655,223762,223761,678,211,220045,8368,8441,225310,8555,8440)
```

This query is expected to return at most 300 records and not more than that.

However I see a message like this as below

[image]

But the table on which this query operates is really huge. Does this indicate the table size? However, I ran this query multiple times a day

Due to this, it resulted in error below

> Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free query bytes scanned. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

How long do I have to wait for this error to go-away? Is the daily limit `1TB`? If yes, then I didn't not use close to `400 GB`.

How to view my daily usage?

If I can `edit quota`, can you let me know which option should I be editing?

Can you help me with the above questions?

Comment: BQ stores data in columns and charges for the data scanned.  `select *` is generally not best practice as it brings in every column ... you will want to select only the columns you need.  Adding partitions to your data can help to limit query costs as well.  As for your other question, I believe the free tier is 1TB of querying per month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing)
"BigQuery charges for queries by using one metric: the number of bytes processed (also referred to as bytes read)", regardless of how large the output size is. What this means is that if you do a count(*) on a 1TB table, you will supposedly be charged $5, even though the final output is very minimal.
Note that due to storage optimizations that BigQuery is doing internally, the bytes processed might not equal to the actual raw table size when you created it.

For the error you're seeing, browse the Google Console to "IAM & admin" then "Quotas", where you can then search for quotas specific to the BigQuery service.

Hope this helps!
Flavien